# How to show the list of data on double click on textbox for autocomplete feature with out typing any letter?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, textbox

I have a textbox upon which autocomplete function is applied,which populates the list data on typing any letter inside it,but i want to show the total list upon double click on the textbox.

Here is the code i have used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#<%=tNALkTxt.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService.asmx/Get") %>',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                scroll: true,
                scrollHeight: 180,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#<%=rtCmbHdn.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });

});



</script>
```

What additional function i need to add to populate the full list on double click on textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                scroll: true,
                scrollHeight: 180,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    }).bind("dblclick",function () {
         $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
    })
}); ;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it,here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

$("#<%=tNALkTxt.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService.asmx/Get") %>',
            data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            scroll: true,
            scrollHeight: 180,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.split('-')[0],
                        val: item.split('-')[1]
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (e, i) {
        $("#<%=rtCmbHdn.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
    },
  minLength: 0
    }).bind('focus', function () { $(this).autocomplete("search"); });

});



</script>
```